# DocsList Functions Not Working in Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-api

I'm a beginner at this, so this error might be on account of faulty coding, but this is why I'm here! lol.

I have written a Sheets function that (in theory) would go through all the files in a particular folder and find all the instances of a particular word and then return the number of instances of that word. Here is the code I wrote:

```
function commentCount(name) {

  var files = DocsList.getFolderById('FOLDER ID GOES HERE').getFiles();
  var counter = 0;

  for(i in files) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(files[i].getId());

    var text = doc.getText();
    text = text.replace( /\./g, "" );
    var textArray = text.split(" ");

      for(w in textArray){
        if(textArray[w] == name){
          counter++;
      }
   }
}
return counter;
}
```

When I call the function in Sheets, an error reads -  Error: You do not have permission to call getFolderById (line 3, file "commentCount")

I've tried using getFolder("Folder name"), and getFolder(path), and the same error occurs. It seems that the DocList functions are not working correctly.

Not sure what the issue is because everything seems fine when I debug the function.

I won't be able to figure out if the rest of my code is sound until I figure out this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume you mean a literal period in this line `text.replace( /./g, "" );`? A `.` is a special character that means "any character". You'll probably want to escape it. `/\./g,""`.

Comment: How exactly are you running the function?

Comment: I do mean a literal period. Thank you for that correction. As for how I am running the function, I would call the function in a Sheet - Example: =commentCount(A3) where A3 is a cell with a name in it.

Comment: I have changed the text.replace function but the change did not fix the issue, sadly.

Comment: Formulas that call scripts functions do not give full permissions. Please read the bottom of [the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions#permissions).

Comment: Well that explains it... Looks like I'm going to have to go about doing this a more round about way... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Phil Bozak clarified that formulas in Spreadsheets that call scripts functions do not get full permissions, which makes it impossible to use getFolderByID function in this case.